# EF Core - The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need some help understanding the error I'm getting when I try to update a product.

I have read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179473/the-merge-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint), and tried the accepted answer (placing a `_context.SaveChanges()` after each table, before the final saving of the complete product), but I still get the same error as described below.

These are the involved models:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // some more properties
    public ICollection<IdentifierForProduct> Identifiers { get; set; }
}

public class IdentifierForProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductIdentifierId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; } // E.g. "4902505154881"

    public ProductIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class ProductIdentifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; } // E.g. "EAN"

    public ICollection<IdentifierForProduct> ProductIdentifiers { get; set; }
}
```

Initially, after form post, the `Identifiers` are set (`VMProduct` is the product view model):

```
List<IdentifierForProduct> Identifiers = new List<IdentifierForProduct>();
if (VMProduct.Identifiers != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < VMProduct.Identifiers.Count; i++)
    {
        Identifiers.Add(new IdentifierForProduct
        {
            ProductId = VMProduct.Id,
            ProductIdentifierId = VMProduct.Identifiers[i].Id,
            Value = VMProduct.Identifiers[i].Value
        });
    }
}
```

Then the product properties are altered according to the changes made in the form:

```
Product DbM = await GetProduct(VMProduct.Id);
// some more properties are set
DbM.Identifiers = Identifiers;
_context.Update(DbM);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This exception is thrown on `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`:

> SqlException: The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_IdentifiersForProducts_ProductIdentifiers_ProductIdentifierId". The conflict occurred in database "MyStore", table "dbo.ProductIdentifiers", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__108_0(Task result)
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+d__32.MoveNext()

This is the `GetProduct()` method:

```
public async Task<Product> GetProduct(int Id)
{
    Product DbM = await _context.Products
        .Include(ic => ic.InCategories)
            .ThenInclude(pc => pc.ProductCategory)
        .Include(t => t.Type)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.Identifiers) // ProductIdentifiersInTypes
                .ThenInclude(i => i.Identifier)
            .Include(t => t.Type)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Properties) // ProductPropertiesInTypes
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Property)
                        .ThenInclude(o => o.Options)
        .Include(p => p.ProductPropertyOptions)
        .Where(p => p.Id == Id)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    return DbM;
}
```

Comment: Without your db schema it's hard to be 100% but your conflicting a foreignkey constraint. i.e. your trying to update a record for a table `IdentifiersForProducts` where the key value  `ProductIdentifierId` isn't in the table `ProductIdentifiers`. Presuming your foreign key is using standard naming conventions

Comment: It might possible that you are trying to update a record whose Foreign Key does not exist. Side Note -- Instead of you calling `_context.Update(DbM)`, you should `Add/Update` the identifier. if relationship exists properly then record will be saved.

Comment: Ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @BDawg I'm sorry, but I don't even remember if I solved it. I have moved on to different projects. I'm just learning this stuff, and still have quite a ways to go.

Answer (score 18):

The reason why this error happens is that your foreign key 'ProductIdentifierId' in 'IdentifierForProduct' probably has a value of 0 here:

```
List<IdentifierForProduct> Identifiers = new List<IdentifierForProduct>();
if (VMProduct.Identifiers != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < VMProduct.Identifiers.Count; i++)
    {
        Identifiers.Add(new IdentifierForProduct
        {
            ProductId = VMProduct.Id,
            ProductIdentifierId = VMProduct.Identifiers[i].Id, //here, your id should be 0
            Value = VMProduct.Identifiers[i].Value
        });
    }
}
```

When Entity Framework Core encounters the value 0 for a foreign key, it throws this kind of error, because it cannot insert the foreign value 0 which is the primary key of some object. Obviously, primary keys cannot be valued 0.

Comment: This helped me, I had a quick for loop to create some sample data, then saving to DB I got this obscure message. Then I realised with your answer that my for loop was starting at 0. #facepalm Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Summary:**

1. Remove auto increment from primary keys and define sequences to generate the Ids for the entities.
2. When the entities are being saved, before saving the entities assign the IDs generated through the sequence to the parent objects and child objects.

**Detailed Answer:**
I encountered a similar issue when creating entities with the foreign key constraints where the parent entities are not yet created. Problem could be explained using the following entity relationship diagram.
[image]

Here the Author has Books and the Book has chapters. Book has the AuthorId which is a FK to Author and Chapter has FKs to Author and Book. All the Ids in the entities are auto increment integers.

**Problem:**
When I create Author, add books and chapters and save them, I get the following exception.

```
List chaptersList1 = new List();
chaptersList1.Add(new Chapter() { ChapterName = "Chapter 1" });
chaptersList1.Add(new Chapter() { ChapterName = "Chapter 2" });
chaptersList1.Add(new Chapter() { ChapterName = "Chapter 3" });

List bookList = new List();
bookList.Add(new Book() { BookName = "Book 1", Chapters = chaptersList1 });

Author author = new Author()
{
    AuthorName = "Author 1",
    Books = bookList
};

using (var context = BookDbContextPoolHelper.GetConnectionFactory().CreateDbContext())
{
    context.Add(author);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Chapter_Author". The conflict occurred in database "TestWork", table "bookstore.Author", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

This is basically saying that when the chapter is being saved, it does not know of a Author with the given Id.

**Resolution:**

1. Remove the auto increment Ids from Author and Book.
2. Create Sequences to generate Ids for the Author and Book.
3. Write an extension method to get the Next value of the sequence for a given sequence.
4. Override the SaveChanges method of the db context and assign the Ids for Author, Book and Chapter before saving the changes.

```
    private void BeforeSavingChanges()
    {
        var newAuthors = base.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is Author && x.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
        foreach (var entry in newAuthors)
        {
            var newAuthor = (Author)entry.Entity;
            newAuthor.Id = this.NextValueForSequence(Sequence.AuthorIdSequence);
            foreach (var newBook in newAuthor.Books)
            {
                newBook.Id = this.NextValueForSequence(Sequence.BookIdSequence);
                newBook.AuthorId = newAuthor.Id;

                foreach (var chapter in newBook.Chapters)
                {
                    chapter.AuthorId = newAuthor.Id;
                    chapter.BookId = newBook.Id;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        BeforeSavingChanges();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Sample project to demonstrate the problem and solution can be found [here](https://github.com/kinathru/FKBookStoreDemo). Problem scenario is in the 'master' and the solution is in the 'fix' branch.

Answer (score -1):

I've had to deal with the same exact problem, and the zeros where 'must have' in my scenario. If that's the case for you, you can always disable the foreign key constraint:

[image: In SSMS: Table -> Keys -> -> Modify]