# "The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" on optional one-to-many-relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables connected with one optional one to many and one non-optional one to many relation. On adding data i get the error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Dependency_CommandGroup_ConditionId". The conflict occurred in database "DatabaseName", table "dbo.CommandGroup", column 'Id'.

Here is the shortened variant of the source code:

```
public class CommandGroup
{
    //....

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Dependency> Conditions { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Dependency> Dependencys { get; set; } = new();

    //....
}

public class Dependency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //non optional Relation
    public int DependentId { get; set; }
    public CommandGroup Dependent { get; set; } = null!;
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    ///...

    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //optional Relation
    public int? ConditionId { get; set; }
    public CommandGroup? Condition { get; set; } 
    public ConditionStatus ConditionStatus { get; set; }
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
}


public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Dependency> builder)
{
    //...

    builder.Property(c => c.Typ).HasConversion<string>();
    builder.Property(c => c.ConditionStatus ).HasConversion<string>();

    builder.HasOne(p => p.Dependent)
        .WithMany(b => b.Conditions)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.DependentId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.HasOne(p => p.Condition)
        .WithMany(b =>b.Dependencys)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.ConditionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
        .IsRequired(false);
}
```

Whats wrwong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [by reading into this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63014275/19297162).

Before adding commandgroup and dependec objects at once, i wasn't handling the optional raltion correctly.

```
//wrong
//dependency.ConditionId = 0;

//correct
dependency.ConditionId = dependency.Condition == null
                         ? null
                         : 0;
```